# What should I do so that I can use a dictionary mapping the filter() function result?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class BNetworkEdge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    edge_type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'b_network_edge'
```

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{0:'direct', 1:'no-direct'}
```

I run this in python shell

```
>>> BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].edge_type
0
```

How to get a result of 'direct' instead of '0'?

Thanks!

Comment: What you probably want to use is the `values()` function, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values, but if you want a more specific answer you need to provide more of your code.  What is 'direct' and 'indirect'?  Which field of BNetworkEdge do you want to be your key, which your value?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I run this in python shell >>> BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].edge_type How to get a result of 'direct' instead of '0'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for this as,

```
@property
def edge_type_value(self):
    _vals = {0:'direct', 1:'no-direct'}
    return _vals[self.edge_type]
```

And your code is like,

```
from django.db import models

class BNetworkEdge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    edge_type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'b_network_edge'

    @property
    def edge_type_value(self):
        _vals = {0:'direct', 1:'no-direct'}
        return _vals[self.edge_type]
```

And you can access it as,

```
In [10]: BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].edge_type_value
Out[10]: 'direct'
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. 
I run this in python shell
>>> BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].edge_type

How to get a result of 'direct' instead of '0'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get dictionary mapping result in your view, you will do something like this:

```
#Your models.py 
class BNetworkEdgeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # The return of query by manager 
        return list(super().get_queryset().values('id', 'data_dict'))


class BNetworkEdge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    edge_type = models.IntegerField()
    objects = BNetworkEdgeManager()

# This goes in views.py 

from .models import BNetworkEdge
def bnetwork_edge_view(request):
    # this context to holds your data as a dictionary
    context  = {}
    dict_data = BNetworkEdge.objects.all()
    context = {'dict_data':dict_data}
    # You can print the content of your context variable 
    # to see the dictionary objects 
    print(context)
    return render(request,"Put Your Html Template Here eg.('network.html/')",context)
```

Well in other to get the value of the edge_type as a dictionary you would need to create a method to the get edge_type handle as a dictionary and link them together with the property decorator! As so:

```
class BNetworkEdge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    edge_type = models.IntegerField()
    objects = BNetworkEdgeManager()
    
    @property
    def get_edge_type(self):
        dict_values = {0:'dict_data', 1:'data'}
        return dict_values[self.edge_type]
   
# Then you call this in your terminal: 
BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].get_edge_type()

#which returns:
[output] {0: 'dict_data'}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I run this in python shell >>> BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].edge_type How to get a result of 'direct' instead of '0'? Thanks!

Comment: Please kindly look at the solution refactored , I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add the choices as proper [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) on your field

```
class BNetworkEdge(models.Model):

    class EdgeTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
        DIRECT = 1, 'direct'
        NO_DIRECT = 2, 'no-direct'

    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    edge_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EdgeTypes.choices)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'b_network_edge'
```

You can then call [`get_edge_type_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) to get the choice label

```
BNetworkEdge.objects.filter()[0].get_edge_type_display()
```